# Se cierra la consola en C

Tags: c

Pues estoy experimentando un poco con los archivos usando lenguaje C. Pero cuando pido al usuario que ingrese nombre del fichero a modificar y su contenido, la consola se cierra y no da respuesta... Pense que se podia ser un problema de memoria, pero no estoy seguro

```
int n, de_1;
char * dir, * con, * r_dir;

printf("(nuevo file = 1, agregar texto en file = 2, sobrescribir file = 3, limpiar file = 4, renombrar file = 5, eliminar file = 6)\n");
scanf("%i", &n);

switch(n)
{
    case 1:

        printf("\nEscribe tu nombre de fichero para ser creado:\n"); scanf("%s", dir); c_file(dir);
        exit(-1);

    break;

    case 2:

        printf("\nNombre del fichero para ser sobreescribido: "); scanf("%s", dir);
        printf("\nContenido del fichero: "); scanf("%s", con); swfile(dir, con);
        exit(-1);

    break;

    case 3:
        printf("\nNombre del fichero para agregar contenido: "); scanf("%s", dir);
        printf("\nContenido del fichero: "); scanf("%s", con); wrfile(dir, con);
        exit(-1);

    break;

    case 4:
        printf("\nNombre del fichero: ");
        scanf("%s", dir);
        printf("\nLimpiando archivo...");
        sleep(2000);
        d_file(dir);
        printf("\nEliminamos su contenido"); exit(-1);
    break;

    case 5:

        printf("\nNombre del fichero a cambiar y nombre nuevo: ");
        scanf("%s %s", dir, r_dir);
        rename(dir, r_dir);
        exit(-1);
    break;

    case 6:
        printf("\nNombre del fichero: ");
        scanf("%s", dir);
        remove(dir);
        exit(-1);
    break;

    default:
        printf("Error");
        exit(-1);
        break;
}
return 0;
```

Soy nuevo en C y lo estoy aprendiendo, el codigo que pase es de la funcion main. Tambien aclaro que funciones como c_file o swfile son funciones propios que cree en otro archivo y adjunte como una cabecera

```
bool vr_file(FILE * fp) // Saber si un fichero existe o no
{
if (fp != NULL) {

    return true;
} else {

    return false;
}
return 0;
}

char c_file(char * dir) //Comprueba si existe el fichero y si NO existe procede a crearlo
  {FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(dir, "r");

if (vr_file(fp) == false) {

    fp = fopen(dir, "w+");
} else {

    return 1;
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}

char rd_file(char * dir) //Lee un fichero y devuelve un conjunto de caracteres
{char * texto;
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(dir, "r");
if (vr_file(fp) == true) {

    while((texto = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", texto);
    }
} else {

    printf("No hay nada escrito");
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}

char wrfile(char * dir, char * text) //Crea un fichero si no existe y SI sobreescribe contenido
{ FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(dir, "w");

if (vr_file(fp) == true) {

    fputs(text, fp);
} else {

    c_file(fp);
    fputs(text, fp);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}

char swfile(char * dir, char * text) // Crea un fichero si no existe, y si existe NO sobreescribe contenido
{FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(dir, "a");

if (vr_file(fp)) {

    fseek(fp, 4, SEEK_END);
    fputs(text, fp);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
  }

int size_f(char * dir) //Devuelve un entero en bytes del peso del fichero
{FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(dir, "r");

if (vr_file(fp)) {

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    return ftell(fp);
}
return 0;
}

char d_file(char * dir) //Limpia el contenido del fichero
{FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(dir, "w");

if (vr_file(fp)) {

    fwrite("", 0, 0, fp);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: de cual de todos los casos hablas? porque todos salen abruptamente con el exit(-1)

Comment: todos los casos excepto el 1. Les quite el exit pero el problema sigue

Comment: Has intentado poner `system("pause");` ?

Comment: resume tu problema a uno solo por vez... por ejemplo, el caso dos decis que anda mal... .Perfecto.. explica que tiene que hacer, y pone las funciones que no pusiste pero que son llamadas. Tal vez el error esta en una de ellas. Y tal vez, si solucionamos un caso, se te solucionen todos.

Comment: Ahora la consola no se cierra... pero me sale un error de Windows de que la consola no responde y el programa finaliza sin haberme hecho los cambios

Comment: Me di cuenta que el problema esta en los casos en donde debo escribir dos datos para hacer el cambio, como el caso 2 que me pide nombre del fichero y su contenido.

Comment: En situaciones en donde la consola no responde, lo primero en lo que hay que sospechar es en un búcle infinito. Asegúrate que los argumentos en fseek sean los adecuados

Comment: Bueno. Ya vi el problema y efectivamente era un problema de memoria. Posteare mi solucion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente era un problema de memoria el causante de este rollo. Lo unico que hice fue reserva espacio de memoria utilizando la funcion de stdlib.h malloc. Seguidamente guarde en ese espacio de memoria los datos que ingresaba el usuario para finalmente hacer los cambios en el fichero...

```
int de_1;
char * dir = NULL, * con = NULL, * r_dir = NULL;

dir = (char *) malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
con = (char *) malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
r_dir = (char *) malloc(32 * sizeof(char));

printf("(New file = 1, Sobrescribir contenido de file = 2, Agregar contenido a file = 3, Limpiar contenido de file = 4, eliminar file = 5, renombrar a file = 6):\n");
scanf("%i", &de_1);

if (de_1 == 1) {

    printf("\nEscribe el nombre del fichero: ");
    scanf("%s", dir);
    c_file(dir);

} else if (de_1 == 2) {

    printf("\nEscribe el nombre del fichero y su contenido a sobreescribir: ");
    scanf("%s %s", dir, con);
    swfile(dir, con);
    printf("\nFichero sobrescribido");

} else if (de_1 == 3) {

    printf("\nEscribe el nombre del fichero y su contenido a agregar: ");
    scanf("%s %s", dir, con);
    swfile(dir, con);
    printf("\nAgregado nuevo contenido");

} else if (de_1 == 4) {

    printf("\nEscribe el fichero a ser limpiado: ");
    scanf("%s", dir);
    printf("\nLimpiando...");
    sleep(2);
    d_file(dir);
    printf("\nFichero limpeado correctamente");

} else if (de_1 == 5) {

    printf("\nEscribe el fichero a ser eliminado: ");
    scanf("%s", dir);
    remove(dir);
    printf("\nEliminado");

} else if (de_1 == 6) {

    printf("\nEscribe el fichero a ser renombrado y su nuevo nombre: ");
    scanf("%s %s", dir, r_dir);
    rename(dir, r_dir);
    printf("\nCambios realizado sastifactoriamente");
}

exit(-1);
free(con);
free(dir);
free(r_dir);
```

Reserve memoria previamente usando la funcion malloc dandole un espacio de 32 * 4 bytes.